# Symfony - Setting Cookie onKernelRequest

Tags: symfony, cookies

i want to be able to set a Cookie onKernelRequest Method, but the cookie is not beeing set, 
Everything else is working fine, what am missing here?
What i want to achieve is that if the user is not logged in and doesnt have the cookie he should see the http basic auth headers.
If the user is logged in or does have the cookie he has access to the preview domains without having to enter their user credentials in http basic auth.

```
const AUTH_USER = 'myuser';
const AUTH_PW = 'mypass';

public function sendAuthorizationHeader()
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Preview Domain"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die();
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $loginSuccessful = false;

    // check if we are on a preview domain
    if (preg_match('/^preview-\d+/', $host)) {
        $user = $request->getUser();
        $cookie = $request->cookies->get('preview_user');
        $phpAuthUser = $request->server->get('PHP_AUTH_USER');
        $phpAuthPw = $request->server->get('PHP_AUTH_PW');

        if (isset($phpAuthUser) && isset($phpAuthPw)) {
            if ($phpAuthUser == self::AUTH_USER && $phpAuthPw == self::AUTH_PW) {
                $loginSuccessful = true;
            }
        } else if ($user === null && $cookie === null) {
            $this->sendAuthorizationHeader();
        }

        if (!$loginSuccessful) {
            $this->sendAuthorizationHeader();
        } else {
            $cookie = new Cookie('preview_user', true, 86400, '/', null, false, false);

            $response = new Response();
            $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
            $response->sendHeaders();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sending cookies should go through the response object, not the request, I guess you should use another event such as onKernelResponse maybe ?

Comment: The thing is, i need this featuew when we request domains such as preview-1234. 

Is this working onKernelResponse too? Pierre?

Comment: I've tried now with onKernelResponse but the cookie is still not beeing set :(

Answer (score 10):

Setting a cookie on a response object doesn't do anything but adding a cookie to that request. You need to return the same response object, so Symfony renders it back to the client. Rendering it yourself is not a good idea, as there might be contents send later and it's not really testable.

It's easier done in a `kernel.response` event listener, since you already have a response there. Remember to use the response that your application creates. Do not create it yourself.

If you set the cookie based on logic that should also be available during the request, you can split it into two event listener methods. One will set a request attribute on `kernel.request`, and the other one will set the cookie on the response on `kernel.response`:

```php
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    // your logic goes here. calculate the $result
    // ...

    $event->getRequest()->attributes->set('my_result', $result);
}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    $myResult = $request->attributes->get('my_result');
    $cookie = new Cookie(/* ... */);

    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
}
```

Comment: cheers for the advice Jakub. Can i add  the onKernelResponse Method just as it is or do i need to configure it in services.yml?

Comment: You obviously need to configure your event listeners as services (tag them). You can add multiple tags to a single service if you want to keep both listeners in a single class.

Comment: Jakub check my answer below please :)

Comment: You shouldn't post comments as answers ;) The example I gave you (and yours, which looks fine at first look) has to work. If it doesn't, you probably missed something or doing something strange (not sure what's going on in your sendAuthorizationHeader(), but it looks wrong to send any headers from a listener).

Comment: The sendAuthorizationHeader is used to send http basic auth header.
Like this:

 public function sendAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Preview"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        die();
    }