# Can't set new cookie

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to set a cookie to save the locale choice.
Using `kernel.response` event, I did this :

```
public function setCookie(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    /** @var Response $response */
    $response=$event->getResponse();
    $cookie=new Cookie('_locale', $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_locale'), strtotime('now + 1 year'), '/', $event->getRequest()->getHttpHost());
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
}
```

`_locale`, if it doesn't exists, is set from `kernel.request` event.

The problem is that after receiving the response on the web browser, the coockie isn't set.
It's not even in the response dump.

<kbd>**Twig dump**</kbd>

```
ParameterBag {#13 ▼
  #parameters: array:2 [▼
    "PHPSESSID" => "5aulgi7dbut4mfjmpgvc48cr2o"
    "REMEMBERME" => "QXBwQnVuZGxlXEVudGl0eVxVc2VyOmNISmxZMmxsYkM1bllXMWxjMEJuYldGcGJDNWpiMjA9OjE1NTAzMzM1OTM6ODFiNTllMmU0MDA4YjdiOWU1Y2Q0ZjJlN2E4Y2ExZWUxOTdkOWE1YjIxNDA0NDdmZTU2MGRj ▶"
  ]
}
HeaderBag {#16 ▼
  #headers: array:11 [▼
    "cookie" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "PHPSESSID=5aulgi7dbut4mfjmpgvc48cr2o; REMEMBERME=QXBwQnVuZGxlXEVudGl0eVxVc2VyOmNISmxZMmxsYkM1bllXMWxjMEJuYldGcGJDNWpiMjA9OjE1NTAzMzM1OTM6ODFiNTllMmU0MDA4YjdiOWU1Y2Q0ZjJlN2E4Y2ExZWUxOTdkOWE1YjIxNDA0NDdmZTU2MGRjOGFiMTAwOWZhZA%3D%3D ◀"
    ]
  ]
}
```

"Fun fact" though, if I add `dump($event); exit();` after `$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);`, I can see my cookie in `event.response.headers`

<kbd>**kernel.response dump**</kbd>

```
FilterResponseEvent {#995 ▼
  -response: Response {#903 ▼
    +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#994 ▼
      #cookies: array:1 [▼
        "sphere.gdn" => array:1 [▼
          "/" => array:1 [▼
            "_locale" => Cookie {#154 ▼
              #name: "_locale"
              #value: "en"
              #domain: "sphere.gdn"
              #expire: 1581376164
              #path: "/"
              #secure: false
              #httpOnly: true
              -raw: false
              -sameSite: null
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
}
```

My listener events are found by Symfony

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                          Priority  
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #10     AppBundle\Service\LocaleHandlerService::setLocale()                                               0         
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------

Registered Listeners for "kernel.response" Event
================================================

 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                     Priority  
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      AppBundle\Service\LocaleHandlerService::setCookie()                                          0         
 ------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing to set my cookie?

Comment: try read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984666/symfony-setting-cookie-onkernelrequest, hope it will be helpful

Comment: @Deadpool Beside the `my_result` attribute, I'm doing the same thing as the only answer provided in that topic. It's why I don't understand why I can't see my cookie.

Comment: Are you actually positive (eg. triple checked) your event handler gets called? Did you check the actual value of `$event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_locale')` ?

Comment: Yes, the event get called, I can dump it. "Fun fact", if I dump `$event`, I can see my cookie in the response. But dumping the response from twig, I don't see it anymore, and it's not set either.

Comment: @ccKep made some edits based on your comment to complement the question.

Comment: Did you try leaving the optional `path` and `domain` fields empty? perhaps even the ttl for testing purposes? (eg. `new Cookie('_locale', $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_locale')`)

Comment: @ccKep Yep, tried that too

Answer (score 0):

Try it set.

```
$cookie=new Cookie('_locale', 'en', strtotime('now + 1 year'));
```

And read

```
$cookies = $request->cookies;
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer makes no sense. Why get cokies from request, when I'm sending a response? Request isn't needed anymore at this point.

Comment: Read  in main controller for test.

Comment: Can't, I'm past the controller at this point... kernel.response is after the controller. And anyway, as I said, it's not in the response dump. Wich mean it failled to set the cookie